# is there a way for having all possible combination from list of lists based on their index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm

I am trying to generate all possible combination of values from lists based on their index , but the index must be different.

If I have a list of lists:

```py
[
    [a1,a2,a3,...,an],
    [b1,b2,b3,...,bn],
    [c1,c2,c3,...,cn],
    ...
]
```

I want to generate all possible combination of a list of the form:

`[a1,b2,c3,...]` or `[a1,a2,b3,...]` or `[b1,a2,a3,...]` but not `[a1,b1,c3,...]`. The last one is not valid because the first two elements in the list have the same index.

I have tried using permutation on the parent list and selecting based on their position in the permutation but I can't get more than 1 item from a list.

Comment: `itertools.product`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply generate the Cartesian product of choices in `a`, `b`,or `c` for each position.

```py
choice_indices = list(itertools.product(range(3), repeat=3))

>>> print(choice_indices)
[(0, 0, 0),  # a1, a2, a3
 (0, 0, 1),  # a1, a2, b3
 (0, 0, 2),  # a1, a2, c3
 (0, 1, 0),  # a1, b2, a3
 ...
 (2, 1, 2),  # c1, b2, c3
 (2, 2, 0),  # c1, c2, a3
 (2, 2, 1),  # c1, c2, b3
 (2, 2, 2)]  # c1, c2, c3
```

You can then recover the
"populated" arrangements using a simple list comprehension:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [10, 20, 30] 
c = [100, 200, 300]

choices = [a, b, c]

populated = [
    [choices[abc][idx] for idx, abc in enumerate(choice)] 
    for choice in choice_indices
]

>>> print(populated)
[[1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 30],
 [1, 2, 300],
 [1, 20, 3],
 ....
 [100, 20, 300],
 [100, 200, 3],
 [100, 200, 30],
 [100, 200, 300]]
```

This can be expressed more concisely as the Cartesian product over the "transpose" of the choices list. That is, the Certesian product of `(a1,b1,c1)`, `(a2,b2,c2)`, ..., `(aN,bN,cN)`. These term sequences can be easily computed as `zip(*choices)`, so the full results can be generated with just the following line:

```
>>> print(list(itertools.product(*zip(*choices))))
[(1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 30),
 (1, 2, 300),
 (1, 20, 3),
 ...
 (100, 20, 300),
 (100, 200, 3),
 (100, 200, 30),
 (100, 200, 300)]
```

Comment: @JonSG Fixed typo in the comments. The second element is always one of `a2`, `b2`, or `c2`. Every entry keeps its fixed position - the only thing that changes between outputs is whether each position is populated from the corresponding position of `a`, `b`, or `c`.

Comment: @JonSG It implies that items from choice list 0 (i.e. `a`) appear multiple times in the final result

Comment: Cool then, I'll have to take a closer look at this to parse it out for myself.